# How to remove xticks from a plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis, xticks

I have a semilogx plot and I would like to remove the xticks. I tried:

```
plt.gca().set_xticks([])
plt.xticks([])
ax.set_xticks([])
```

The grid disappears (ok), but small ticks (at the place of the main ticks) remain. How to remove them?

Answer (score 729, accepted):

The [`plt.tick_params`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tick_params.html) method is very useful for stuff like this.  This code turns off major and minor ticks and removes the labels from the x-axis.

Note that there is also [`ax.tick_params`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params) for `matplotlib.axes.Axes` objects.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot(range(10))
plt.tick_params(
    axis='x',          # changes apply to the x-axis
    which='both',      # both major and minor ticks are affected
    bottom=False,      # ticks along the bottom edge are off
    top=False,         # ticks along the top edge are off
    labelbottom=False) # labels along the bottom edge are off
plt.show()
plt.savefig('plot')
plt.clf()
```

[image]

Answer (score 265):

Not exactly what the OP was asking for, but a simple way to disable all axes lines, ticks and labels is to simply call:

```
plt.axis('off')
```

Answer (score 175):

Alternatively, you can pass an empty tick position and label as

```
# for matplotlib.pyplot
# ---------------------
plt.xticks([], [])
# for axis object
# ---------------
# from Anakhand May 5 at 13:08
# for major ticks
ax.set_xticks([])
# for minor ticks
ax.set_xticks([], minor=True)
```

Answer (score 92):

Here is an alternative solution that I found on the [matplotlib mailing list](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/turning-off-tick-marks-tp27160p27162.html):

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

x = range(1000)
ax = plt.axes()
ax.semilogx(x, x)
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
```

[image: graph]

Answer (score 58):

There is a better, and simpler, solution than the one given by John Vinyard. Use `NullLocator`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(range(10))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
plt.show()
plt.savefig('plot')
```

Answer (score 35):

Try this to remove the labels (but not the ticks):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.setp( ax.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
```

[example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/shared_axis_demo.html)

Answer (score 25):

This snippet might help in removing the xticks only.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt    
plt.xticks([])
```

This snippet might help in removing the xticks and yticks both.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt    
plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])
```

Answer (score 13):

Those of you looking for a short command to switch off all ticks and labels should be fine with

```py
plt.tick_params(top=False, bottom=False, left=False, right=False,
                labelleft=False, labelbottom=False)
```

which allows type `bool` for respective parameters since version matplotlib>=2.1.1

For custom tick settings, the docs are helpful:

https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html

Answer (score 4):

```py
# remove all the ticks (both axes), and tick labels on the Y axis
plt.tick_params(top='off', bottom='off', left='off', right='off', labelleft='off', labelbottom='on')
```

Answer (score 4):

Modify the following rc parameters by adding the commands to the script:

```
plt.rcParams['xtick.bottom'] = False
plt.rcParams['xtick.labelbottom'] = False
```

A sample matplotlibrc file is depicted in [this section](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html?highlight=matplotlibrc) of the matplotlib documentation, which lists many other parameters like changing figure size, color of figure, animation settings, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove tick labels but keep the ticks and grids, this code snippet will work.

```py
plt.gca().axes.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
plt.gca().axes.yaxis.set_ticklabels([])
plt.grid(alpha = 0.2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to this problem is to set the color of the `xticks` to White or to whatever the background color is. This will hide the text of the xticks but not the xticks itself.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot()
plt.xticks(color='white')
plt.show()
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfUPm.png)

Comment: Please provide code examples as text formatted as code to make it easier for others to copy and test.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to simply change the visibility:

`ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)`