# How can I remove xtics from an axis in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

I'm using subplots in matplotlib. Since all of my subplots have the same x-axis, I only want to label the x-axis on my bottom plot. How can I remove xtics from just one axis?

Comment: Do you want to get rid of just the tick labels, or the actual tick lines themselves? If it's just the labels, check out the demo [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html) where there are several examples using subplots.

Comment: Just the labels, I suppose.

Comment: @Bill: That demo uses matplotlib.pyplot. Is there a way to do this acting directly on the `figure` objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dan, if you've set up your plots in an OOP way using

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax_arr = subplots(3, 1, sharex=True)
```

then it should be easy to hide the x-axis labels using something like

```
plt.setp([a.get_xticklabels() for a in f.axes[:-1]], visible=False)
# or
plt.setp([a.get_xticklabels() for a in ax_arr[:-1]], visible=False)
```

But check out [this link](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html) and some of the further down examples will prove useful.

**Edit:**

If you can't use `plt.subplots()`, I'm still assuming you can do

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)

ax1.plot(x1, y1)
ax2.plot(x2, y2)

plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
```

If you have more than 2 subplots, such as

```
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(N11)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(N12)
...
axN = fig.add_subplot(N1N)

plt.setp([a.get_xticklabels() for a in (ax1, ..., axN-1)], visible=False)
```

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12998430/remove-xticks-in-a-matplot-lib-plot), the following works!

```
plt.tick_params(\
    axis='x',          # changes apply to the x-axis
    which='both',      # both major and minor ticks are affected
    bottom='off',      # ticks along the bottom edge are off
    top='off',         # ticks along the top edge are off
    labelbottom='off') # labels along the bottom edge are off
```