# Passing an empty string to matplotlib's yticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, figure

[This webpage](http://gael-varoquaux.info/computers/pyreport/example2.html) has led me to believe that I can pass an empty string to `matplotlib.yticks` in order to turn off the y-ticks of a figure.

However, when I attempt to do this, I get the following error:

```
In [1]: from pylab import *

In [2]: figure()
Out[2]: <matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0xb69d43cc>

In [3]: yticks('')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-7ead106262fa> in <module>()
----> 1 yticks('')

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.pyc in yticks(*args, **kwargs)
   1631     elif len(args)==1:
   1632         locs = ax.set_yticks(args[0])
-> 1633         labels = ax.get_yticklabels()
   1634     elif len(args)==2:
   1635         locs = ax.set_yticks(args[0])

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.pyc in get_yticklabels(self, minor, which)
   2912         return cbook.silent_list('Text yticklabel',
   2913                                   self.yaxis.get_ticklabels(minor=minor,
-> 2914                                                             which=which))
   2915 
   2916     @docstring.dedent_interpd

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axis.pyc in get_ticklabels(self, minor, which)
   1212         if minor:
   1213             return self.get_minorticklabels()
-> 1214         return self.get_majorticklabels()
   1215 
   1216     def get_majorticklines(self):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axis.pyc in get_majorticklabels(self)
   1166     def get_majorticklabels(self):
   1167         'Return a list of Text instances for the major ticklabels'
-> 1168         ticks = self.get_major_ticks()
   1169         labels1 = [tick.label1 for tick in ticks if tick.label1On]
   1170         labels2 = [tick.label2 for tick in ticks if tick.label2On]

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axis.pyc in get_major_ticks(self, numticks)
   1295         'get the tick instances; grow as necessary'
   1296         if numticks is None:
-> 1297             numticks = len(self.get_major_locator()())
   1298         if len(self.majorTicks) < numticks:
   1299             # update the new tick label properties from the old

TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

What's the deal?  If this method for turning off the y-ticks is incorrect, what is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `yticks` function from matplotlib expects a list as an argument rather than a string. Thus, to turn off the y-ticks,

```
In [1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
In [2]: plt.figure()
Out[2]: <matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x10ef23710>

In [3]: plt.yticks([])
Out[3]: ([], <a list of 0 Text yticklabel objects>)
```

For more control over ticks in matplotlib, consider using `tick_params` as pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32814783/4717663).

Answer (score 1):

The accepted solution for this question should achieve what you want, and give you more control over what is displayed.

[Remove xticks in a matplot lib plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12998430/remove-xticks-in-a-matplot-lib-plot)

For example, for turning off all ticks on the y axis:

```
>>> from pylab import *
>>> figure()
>>> plot(arange(10))
>>> tick_params(axis='y', which='both', left='off', right='off', labelleft='off')
>>> show()
```

Comment: cool, thanks.  is passing an empty string something that used to be supported but isn't anymore?