# Turning off ticks in matplotlib for all plots (using rc)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Is there a way to turn of xticks and yticks using matplotlibrc or another matplotlib config method? The only way I see currently is to set the sizes of ticks and tick labels to zero. That seems an odd way, given that I can `set_xticks(())`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12998430/remove-xticks-in-a-matplot-lib-plot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [`tick_params`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.tick_params)

```
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='both')
```

This is affecting `both` axis (other options are `x` or `y`). It also affects `both` major and minor ticks (other options are `major` or `minor`)

This will leave ticks around the outer edge, but not in the plot. If you want the edge ticks removed, you can add:

```
bottom='off'
top='off'
left='off'
right='off'
```

If you want to remove the labels, you'll want to turn these `off`

```
labelbottom='off'
labeltop='off'
labelleft='off'
labelright='off'
```

Comment: That's great! It seems like a very long command to turn off ticks but it seems to work. It seems to work persistently, but I can't see that mentioned in the docs.