# How to set labels with MATPLOTLIB?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have my image
[image]

Then I try this

```
   #!/usr/bin/python
import os,sys
import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

jpgfile = Image.open("t002.jpg")
fig = plt.imshow(jpgfile)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_xlabel('normlized resistivities')
ay.set_ylabel('normlized velocities')
fig.savefig("fig.jpg")
```

But then I have

```
AttributeError: 'AxesImage' object has no attribute 'add_subplot'
```

How to setup xlabel and ylabel and then save new image as a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be enough to simply do

```
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(jpgfile)
plt.xlabel('normlized resistivities')
plt.ylabel('normlized velocities')
plt.savefig('out.jpg')
```

Your current error is because `imshow` does not return a `Figure`.

Answer (score 1):

Hannes's answer works fine, but sometimes you need the `ax` object, so I tend to do this sort of thing:

```
import os,sys
import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

jpgfile = Image.open("t002.jpg")

# Set up the figure and axes.
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))  # ...or whatever size you want.
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# Draw things.
plt.imshow(jpgfile)
ax.set_xlabel('normalized resistivities')
ax.set_ylabel('normalized velocities')

# Save and show.
plt.savefig("fig.jpg")
plt.show()
```

By the way, I recommend [saving as PNG](http://www.agilegeoscience.com/blog/2012/8/7/how-to-choose-an-image-format.html) for figures containing text and other elements with fine detail. And [setting a high `dpi`](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure) for the saved figure.

Comment: @
Works perfect,but how to get rid of 0,100,200,300 ticks I do not need them at all?

Comment: @ kwinkunks
Works perfect but how to get rid of 0,100,200 ticks?

Comment: There are lots of ways to do most things in mpl! `ax.set_axis_off()` will turn off the whole border, for example, or `ax.set_xticks([]); ax.set_yticks([])` will remove the ticks only. You can also use [`plt.tick_params`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12998531/3381305).

Comment: Note that `imshow` can be an `Axes` method if you want it to be: http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow

Comment: tom - Thanks! Good point, I corrected my post. In think I use `plt.imshow` because then `plot.colorbar()` 'just works'... and I've never taken the trouble to figure out the way to do this with `ax`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best way is to actually plot the image, and only show the axis labels (hide axis and ticks)

[This reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9295472/5903959) may be the way to go

Answer (score 0):

You could just use plt.xlabel('xlabel')

Comment: But how,I tied like this fig.plt.xlabel('normlized resistivities'),but got     raise AttributeError(name) AttributeError: plt