# Set bottom, top, left, right tick visibility in matplotlibrc

Tags: python, matplotlib

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12998531/6421322) is a question about turning off the ticks on a given side of a set of axes by using the `tick_params` method. I want to change the `top` and `right` properties to off by default in my `matplotlibrc` but I don't see how that is to be done, as the ticks section of the `matplotlibrc` file deals with things in terms of `xtick` and `ytick`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

After sleuthing around on the matplotlib github, I found what I was looking for: the [upcoming version 2.x branch](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v2.x/matplotlibrc.template), at the time I am writing this, has `xtick.top`, etcetera, as parameters in the new matplotlibrc template.

So the answer is that at the time of this writing, that functionality may not be available for templates, and @user2927356's method may be all I can use until matplotlib 2.x comes out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty new to matplotlib myself, but i belive you can do something like this:

```
pl.tick_params(bottom="off", top="off")
```

Comment: Well, that works for one plot, but I'm trying to make it the default behavior of a custom theme.