# Hide upper/right tick markers using rcparams/mplstyle

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am currently using a variant of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11417222/2552873) to eliminate the top/right edges on my plots. However, I would like to be able to add this to my .mplstyle file instead of calling this function for every plot I create. Is there a way to achieve this functionality using the style parameters, or even by calling something once at the beginning of my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
axes.spines.top : False
axes.spines.right : False
```

in a mpstyle file to turn off spines. Unfortunately, [this recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38750147/812786) indicates that ticks cannot currently be controlled from an rc or style file like this, and I haven't yet found a way either. However, in matplotlib 2.0 you should be able to write:

```
xtick.top : False
ytick.right : False
```

(In fact, this appears to be the default style for 2.0, according to [the template file](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v2.x/matplotlibrc.template#L362).)

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I guess that will do in the meantime. Mostly unrelated, but is there a date for the 2.0 release? I can only find info about when various betas are out.

Comment: Glad to help! No idea, I've been watching the developer mailing list and haven't seen anything about a specific date yet either.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @user812786's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39884034/11100315):
You can remove ticks while keeping the spines by changing the size of the ticks to zero. This works in any version of matplotlib.

In your .mplstyle file write:

```
xtick.major.size: 0
xtick.minor.size: 0
ytick.major.size: 0
ytick.minor.size: 0
```