# How do I remove these black marks using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I'm creating a board game using python and matplotlib. this is my first time using matplotlib and I have learnt from Google.

I was wondering if there was a way to remove these little black lines along my axis (Highlighted in red boxes). 
[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLwuI.png)

I have added the grid lines by using:

```
plt.grid(True)
```

and i have hidden the axes by using:

```
frame1 = plt.gca()
frame1.axes.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
frame1.axes.yaxis.set_ticklabels([])
```

Any help would be wonderful. Reply to this if you need anymore information

Kind Regards.

Comment: My general advice with nitpicky things in matplotlib is to deal with it, or write a better plotting library from scratch.  I doubt there's a way with vanilla matplotlib.

Comment: @ChootsMagoots Can you please not comment below just any random matplotlib question that you personally doubt it to have a solution?! As I see it, most problems do have a solution, especially such straight forward things like this. Apart Matplotlib is open source and users are invited to contribute to the code; why would you write a new library instead of improving the existing one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12998430/remove-xticks-in-a-matplotlib-plot) and [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.tick_params)

Seems like the most generally accepted answer is using the `tick_params()` method

```
plt.tick_params(
    axis='both',       # changes apply to the x-axis
    which='both',      # both major and minor ticks are affected
    left='off',        # ticks along the left edge are off
    right='off',       # ticks along the right edge are off
    bottom='off',      # ticks along the bottom edge are off
    top='off')         # ticks along the top edge are off
```

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly and is exactly what I wanted. Cheers!