# Making ticks invisible pandas hist graph using pandas dataframe.hist api

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have tried everything using kwargs, set_visible, and other suggestions given in the docs but have not been able to make x_ticks disappear. Can you guys help me do this.

One of the approaches suggested is following but it complains ax is numpy array and that has no affect is this

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)   # Hide Ticks
ns = dummy.hist(bins=20, ax=ax)
```

This produces following - as you can see x ticks make the graph unreadable.

[image]

**Solved**

ns is of type ndarray, the shape of that is determined by the default layout: in my case it is (3,2). I had to call set_xticks on individual subplots as shown below

```
rows, cols = ns.shape
for r in range(rows):
    for c in range(cols):
        ns[r,c].set_xticks([])
```

[image]

Comment: This is related to matplotlib. Added tag. Possible duplicate of [Remove xticks in a matplotlib plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12998430/remove-xticks-in-a-matplotlib-plot)

Comment: Those are not the ticks. Those are ticklabels. Consider setting fewer ticks.

Comment: Can you try using dummy.hist() to get xticks to disappear. I have tried dummy.plot(kind='hist', subplots=True) but that call is considerably slower for my data.

Comment: @AntonvBR, Pandas dataframe's plot api may be using matplotlib under the covers but my question is specific to using data frame.hist and not matplotlib.plt.

Comment: @smishra Sure, but to manipulate the graphs you are using the matplotlib functions.