# Setting xticks in sns.swarmplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, swarmplot

I have some problems with setting xticks in swarmplot and pointplot in seaborn (though with traditional plt.plot it's OK). When I use typical commands like:

```
plt.xticks([2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
```

or:

```
ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.LinearLocator(8))
```

xticks are only in a short range which doesn't cover the whole x axis.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1D5Q.jpg

[image]

(left subplot on the image). When I dont't type plt.xticks(... then I get something like on the right subplot.

My code is here:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

df = pd.read_csv('dane/iris.csv')
df['Legend'] = df['variety']
df['variety'].replace( {'Setosa':1, 'Versicolor':2, 'Virginica':3}, inplace = True)

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (13,7), facecolor = 'white')

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
sns.swarmplot(df['sepal.length'], df['sepal.width'], hue = df['Legend'], ax = ax1)
plt.xlabel('Sepal length', fontsize = 14)
plt.ylabel('Sepal width', fontsize = 14)
plt.xticks([])
plt.xticks([2,3,4,5,6,7,8])

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
sns.swarmplot(df['petal.length'], df['petal.width'], hue = df['Legend'], ax = ax2)
plt.xlabel('Petal length', fontsize = 14)
plt.ylabel('Petal width', fontsize = 14)

plt.savefig(Figure = fig, fname = 'iris.png')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove xticks in a matplotlib plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12998430/remove-xticks-in-a-matplotlib-plot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`swarmplot` is a categorical plot. It plots categories on the x axis. Using `plt.xticks([2,3,4,5,6,7,8])` you are setting ticks for the categories 2 to 8, but you have many more categories in your plot.

For the data in use it does not look like a categorical plot is actually much of use. You may rather use a scatter plot, which is a numerical plot in both dimensions.

You may use [`ax.scatter()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html) or [`sns.scatterplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html#seaborn.scatterplot) instead.

Comment: Thanks, it's working. As I just found out, sns.scatterplot is available since the newest version which was released last month so that's why it didn't work until I made an update.