# Removing label in Boxplot in Python

Tags: python, boxplot

I'm unable to remove the label "Age" under each box plot shown below. Its autogenerated and can't get rid of it. Here is my code and output:

```
dataset.boxplot(column=['Age'], by=None, ax=None, fontsize=None, rot=0, 
grid=True, figsize=None, layout=None, return_type=None)
plt.suptitle('Attrition by Age')
plt.xlabel('test')
plt.title('test6')
plt.subplot(121)
plt.xlabel('test2')
plt.title('test3')
plt.ylabel('test5')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lfrh9.png)

Comment: It is the `xtick`. You can remove it by `plt.xticks([])`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because here "Age" is not an axis label, instead it is a tick. So you can add something like this:

```py
     plt.xticks([1], [''])
```

to remove the first tick.
And there are many other ways to remove or change ticks. For example, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12998430/remove-xticks-in-a-matplotlib-plot) describes how to remove ticks on different axes.