# How can I fix this error when trying to hide y axis labels on matplotlib axis

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm attempting to hide the y-axis labels on a matplotlib axis. There seems to be an error that some of the labels are hidden but others are not. Is this a bug and is there a way to turn off all the labels? Is it the way that I'm plotting?

Note: I'm only showing half my plot the other half is a cartopy map.

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import cartopy.crs as ccrs
    from cartopy.io.img_tiles import Stamen
    import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader
    from cartopy.feature import ShapelyFeature
    import os
    import pickle
    import pandas as pd
    import geopandas as gpd
    from shapely.geometry import Point
    from pathlib import Path

    fig=plt.figure(figsize=(16,9), dpi=300, constrained_layout=True)
    gs0=fig.add_gridspec(1,2)

    gs00=gs0[0].subgridspec(10,1)
    gs01=gs0[1].subgridspec(1,1)

    data_dir='/data/files/'
    ext_=f'*.pkl'
    p=Path(data_dir).glob(ext_)
    s=[str(i) for i in p]

    for i,j in enumerate(s):
        ax=fig.add_subplot(gs00[i,0])
        f=pickle.load(open(j, 'rb'))
        
        ax.loglog(f[0], f[2])
        ax.margins(x=0)
        ax.set_yticklabels([])

    ax2=fig.add_subplot(gs01[0,0], projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `plt.tick_params()`
See explainations from this topic [Remove xticks in a matplotlib plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12998430/remove-xticks-in-a-matplotlib-plot)

Modification for y-axis:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot(range(10))
plt.tick_params(
    axis='y',          # changes apply to the y-axis
    which='both',      # both major and minor ticks are affected
    left=False,        # ticks along the left edge are off
    labelleft=False)   # labels along the left edge are off
plt.show()
```

[image]