# Custom HeatMap Issue on Scale and legend

Tags: python, heatmap

I try to create a custom heatmap but have an issue on the y scale.

The code I built is the following one :

```
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['red','green'])
bounds=[-1,1]
norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)
heatmap = plt.pcolor(np.array(result), cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
plt.colorbar(heatmap, ticks=[-1,0,1])
```

Where `result` is an array of 3 Column 6 Row Which contains -1 or 1 values

[image]

How can I edit it in order to get

```
0 1 2 3
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the tick range and frequency:

```
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 4, 1.0))
```

Will make ticks from 0 to 4 (excluding 4, so until 3), with an interval of 1 between them.

Comment: Does a way exist to hide the axis value ? (Display Nothing rather than 1 2 3)  ?

Comment: Yes, see this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12998430/remove-xticks-in-a-matplotlib-plot