# matplotlib last tick label still visible

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph

I need to hide all the ticks labels on my x axis, so I used :

```
plt.xticks(color='w')
plt.title(name)
```

It did hid all the labels except the last one. Any idea on how I could hide it ?
At first my x axis was the index and it worked fine, then i changed it to a timestamp and the problem appeared.
Thanks

[my plot]

[image: 1]

Comment: I do not think that setting the color to white is the correct way to remove the ticks. What if you have a different background color? Or what if your background is a gradient? To remove the ticks, read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12998430/remove-xticks-in-a-matplotlib-plot

Comment: @HiFilethebestfilemanager I indeed found something that solved my problem on your link. Thank you, have a nice day

Comment: You may spend a while to write an answer to your question and summarize what exactly solved your issue. This will help others in case they have similar problems. Nice day to you too.

Comment: That’s not a tick label it’s the tick offset value